# Python get list of all enclosing files

Tags: python

I have been at this for a few hours... how to use python to get all enclosing files from a folder... now by enclosing I mean all the files enclosed within a folder within a folder etc.  So all the files beyond a certain point using Python.

I have tried to use glob.glob() and listdir() to do this, but those will just only work within the first level of code.  I could get this to work if there was a way that python could differentiate between a file and a folder?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `os.walk()`. It will give you a list of files and folders in each directory under the starting directory.

Comment: I knew there was something in python to do this... Thank you.